# Show a form on click of ahef

Tags: jquery

I have an MVC app that I'm creating. There are 2 links: Home, Register. When the home page loads the registration form is hidden by CSS (#register_container{ 
    display:none; 
}

When I click the "Register link, which is a aref with the id "registration", the jquery code is as follows:

```
$("#registration").click(function() {
        $("#register_container").$("#form1").toggle();

});
```

This doesnt seem to work. How can I make my form show when I click on the "Registration" link?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your html code

Comment: [Working with selections | jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/working-with-selections/)

Comment: The form flashes on the screen but then disappears on "Register".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#registration").click(function() {
        $("#register_container").toggle();

});
```

Here's a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/23889/

Comment: My mistake....there is no #form1" ....heres the html code:
<div id="register_container">
    <div class="main">
            <form>...
            </form>
        </div>
</div>

Comment: See the updated answer, you hide `register_container` but were trying to show the form it self.

Comment: I changed my css to hide the form but now when I click on "Register" the form flashes on the screen then disappears.

Comment: Please provide an example with full details.

Comment: My html is:
<div id="register_container">
    <div class="main">
            <form class="form" method="post" action="#">
            ...
            </form>
        </div>
</div>

my css is:
#register_container{ 
    display:none; 
}

my script is:
$("#registration").click(function() {
        $("#register_container).toggle();
       
    });
my clicked element is:
<a href='?controller=home?action=register' id="registration">Register</a>

Comment: At this point the toggle works, however the form flashes on the screen then disappears. I tried using a href links and I tried using jquery window.location both of which have the same result.

How can I get the form to stay visible on the screen when clicking "Register"?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer but not from this site. To prevent the flash I used javascripts event.stopImmediatePropagation() & e.PreventDefault.

Thank you very much...